# Mongo Rails Driver - ReplSetConnection - (Slave downtime)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I've a question about the ReplSetConnection.

My setup is a mongo ReplSet with 2 servers and a initializer file (rails 2.3.3)

> MO_SET = Mongo::ReplSetConnection.new([@settings["hostA"],
>   @settings["portA"]], [@settings["hostB"], @settings["portB"]],
>   {:pool_size => 5}) 
>   MO_DB =  MO_SET.db(@settings["database"])

If hostA is the master and hostB  goes down the error occurs

> Mongo::ConnectionFailure (Failed to connect any given host:port):
>   mongo (1.1.5) lib/./lib/mongo/repl_set_connection.rb:116:in `connect'

How can I prevent this because the master is still up and running?

Thanks